# Heroku Docker Container - Illegal Instruction when trying to run the application

Tags: docker, heroku

I've been attempting to get a Docker image running on Heroku for some testing purposes based on the Dockerfile written by a friend of mine:

https://github.com/johncoder/simc-web

I can test and run this locally just fine, but once I get it uploaded to Heroku, a POST to the running container yields the following error from CURL:

```
curl -x POST --data "armory=us,drenden,cataia" https://hdingo-bot- 
simc.herokuapp.com/simc
curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: POST
```

Which is not overly helpful, and also doesn't print anything to the logs in the container either.

So a little more indepth analysis, and from a bash command inside of the running container, I can attempt to call the simc binary manually... but this results in an Illegal Instruction error:

```
/usr/bin $ simc
Illegal instruction
```

The only thing I can find so far, is that perhaps the underlying chipset doesn't support what I'm attempting to run? But it also doesn't seem to be extremely common.

Thanks!

Comment: It is possible the compiled package requires being root, which Heroku doesn't provide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#run-the-image-as-a-non-root-user

Comment: I don't believe so, running locally seems to work just fine without having to run as root.

Comment: Docker always runs as root by default.